# Search by keywords with boolean operators

Tags: search, tags

Is there a way to tell WordPress to only search the keywords and nothing else? For example, if I searched "yellow, red, white" it would only display posts with one or a combination of those keywords in it.

Is this possible in WP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [WordPress › Relevanssi - A Better Search « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/relevanssi/)

Comment: +1 for Relevanssi.  It is a great search overhaul for WP, and gives you a LOT more control over results.  Best part is, it hooks into the core search function so you don't have replace any front-end code (no special search boxes, etc).

Comment: I can't seem to find anything that relates to displaying posts that include ONLY the keywords though. Anyone mind pointing me in the right direction?

Comment: @realph: read the docs for the plugin; it supports what you call "keyword' search results. Putting "keywords" in quotes tells as earch engine to only display results with those keywords.